# Changing json query delimiter with Json.net

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I'm working with Newtonsoft Json and in order to query a json string, I use the `SelectToken` method which uses "." as a delimiter to query the hierarchy of the json as described in the docks:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm

Is there some way to change the delimiter from using "." to using ":"? meaning that instead of querying for example "a.b.c", I could query for "a:b:c"? It doesn't have to use the `SelectToken`, but I still got to have a way to reach a specific path with given keys (like the a,b,c in my example above)

Comment: I don't think so, but have to ask the obvious question: Why? What's so hard about using periods?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Not hard to develop. Just that people who are using what I develop, are used to working with json from probably some other library which used the ":" delimiter

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to change it. The argument provided to `SelectToken` is a path which Json.Net internally parses and converts to `JPath`. If you check the source for same, you can see `.` is hardcoded as one of the switch-cases in `ParsePath` method of `JPath` class. [Check here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/JPath.cs#L138)
and [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/JPath.cs#L73) too.

Comment: Might there be something else which is not SelectToken which can take a path with a different delimiter?